# How to add separate Html elements on a button click on Python Dash

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

A very trivial scenario I am trying to achieve using Python dash. Adding similar elements on each button click one after another.

Below is the code.

```py
app.layout = {
  html.Button(id='add-element-button', n_clicks=0, children='Add Input Element'),
  html.Div(id="layout")
}

@app.callback(Output('layout', 'children'),
              [Input('add-element-button', 'n_clicks')])
def add_strategy_divison(val):
    if val:
        return html.Div(id=f"heading_element_{val}",
            [
                html.H1(id=f"heading_{val}", children=f"{val} Heading"),
            ]
            )
    else:
        raise PreventUpdate
```

What seems to be happening is instead of adding new elements, it just overwrites the first heading element (which is successfully created on first click) with the new one along with the new id.

Does anyone have any idea what could be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour you described makes perfect sense. You return an new div-element which means you overwrite the children attribute of the *layout* element. This way you will always replace existing children.

For this to work the way you want it you need to get the current children of your *layout* element and add your new element to it. Pass the current children as a *State* object to your callback. Now append your element to children an return the list.

```
@app.callback(
    Output('layout', 'children'),
    [Input('add-element-button', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('layout', 'children')],
)
def add_strategy_divison(val, children):
    if val:
        el = html.Div(id=f"heading_element_{val}", [
            html.H1(id=f"heading_{val}", children=f"{val} Heading"),
        ])
        children.append(el)
        return children
    else:
        raise PreventUpdate
```

Comment: And how can we use these as inputs in other callbacks? Would love to hear your take!! Thank you.